# How to set OpenCV window no topbar , and keep input focus at console after namewindow?

Tags: c++, c, opencv, winapi, real-time

I made a subroutine that modifies the parameters of an industrial camera without using mouse.
I wish user could enter camera parameters from keyboard  in the console window,and see the current situation(change) in the OpenCV window which name as "Viwer".
In addition,i hope user can't close the window by click the X in topbar.User can only close the viwer window by input "ESC".

So,I try this:

```
int __GetAndSetModifyValue(CInstantCamera *camera)
{
  unsigned int flags = { SWP_SHOWWINDOW  };
  namedWindow("Viwer", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
  HWND win_handle = FindWindow(NULL, "Viwer");
  SetWindowLong(win_handle, GWL_STYLE, GetWindowLong(win_handle, GWL_EXSTYLE));
  while(true)
  {
    GetInput(input)....;
    if(input==esc) break;
    SetWindowPos(win_handle, HWND_BOTTOM, x, y, pictureWidth, pictureHeight, flags);
    ShowWindow(win_handle, SW_SHOW);}
    change camera(input)..... maybe error return
  }
return 0;
}
```

There have two question:

(1)namewindow whill change the keyboard input focus from console window to OpenCV window,so i need to click consloe window after OpnenCV window show.How to keep the input focus at console?

(2)Actually,I would keep use SetWindowPos(win_handle, HWND_BOTTOM, x, y, pictureWidth, pictureHeight, flags) to keep Viwer is same size with pircutre.But that will let Viwer keep flash to bottom.
Maybe I should try some function like resizewindow?

P.S I have search some solutions like GetConsoleWindow.How does it actually work?

Comment: note: OpenCV is C++, WinAPI is C. if anyone feels like debating over the tagging of both languages, be aware of that first.

Comment: you might need to write your own GUI code. OpenCV's GUI facilities are convenient but not flexible. *maybe* you could get the handle of the imshow window from opencv and then defocus that window (or get the console handle and refocus that).

Comment: Seems like no one have experience for this kind of problem. I'm still very interested in this question,let me know if anyone have a preposal.
Thank for your suggestion,I will try make my own GUI. @Christoph Rackwitz